# Почему пишет NameError: name 'v' is not defined?

Tags: python, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Изучаю сортировки.Подскажите почему не работает?

```
def bubble_sort(nums):
    swapped = True
    v = 0
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[i] > nums[i + 1]:
                nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i]
                swapped = True
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[i] > nums[i + 1]:
                v + 1

random_list_of_nums = [8,6,7,5,4,2,3,1]
bubble_sort(random_list_of_nums)
print(random_list_of_nums)
print (v)
```

Answer (score 1):

потому что `v` это локальная переменная, она существует только внутри `bubble_sort`, её надо вернуть и сохранить в переменную

```
def bubble_sort(nums):
    ...
    return v

random_list_of_nums = [8,6,7,5,4,2,3,1]
v = bubble_sort(random_list_of_nums)
print(random_list_of_nums)
print (v)
```

но результатом всегда будет `0` т.к. место `v + 1` надо писать `v += 1`